# How to modify res.body in last restify response handler?

Tags: node.js, restify

I want to create handler at the end of the chain that is modifying response body before it is sent to the client.

**Example**

```
restify.get('/api/persons', getAllPersons(), anotherFunction(), modifyBodyFunction());
```

The problem is that some of the handlers prior in the chain (for instance `anotherFunction()`, is calling `res.send()` and thus sending the response back to the client.

Is there any way I can modify the res.body in `modifyBodyFunction()` even the handler prior is calling the res.send()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `next()` instead `res()` in the middlewares like `anotherFunction()`

If you send the response before (in a middleware) you cannot do anything after that and it's not correct.

Please read this about [Middlewares](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html)

PS
Of course you can send response in a Middleware, but that response should be sent only if you need to break the chain due to some errors.

Comment: But are there no way of modifying the response before it is sent to client in the last handler? Like, in some situtions, anotherFunction() should call res.send() and then it should be the last handler in the chain, in other it should use next().  My question is in more general sense, are responses sent to next handler when calling res.send() or is it sent immediately to client and it can never be modified in next handlers?

Comment: The second you said, as you call res.send() or res.end() (and similar res.json(), etc...) your response is sent to the user and the call terminated. You have to modify your response in the middlewares and use next() to pass it to the next one until you reach the final call to send the response.